# How to upload file with user-defined meta information that contains dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

Using Python3.8 and boto3==1.16.53

Here is my code using boto3 to upload zip file with user-defined meta information.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object = s3.Object(s3_bucket_name, s3_path)

object.put(Body=my_random_file, Metadata={"my_meta": "any_string"})
```

code above successfully uploads my_random_file to S3 bucket and user-defined meta is below

```
"x-amz-meta-my_meta": "any_string"
```

Code is working but I would like to put dict type meta like below

```
  "x-amz-meta-my_meta": {
    "my_meta_1": [
      "any_string"
    ]
  }
```

so I can pass a list into the value.
Is there a way to do this using boto3?

Comment: " list into the value"  - what do you mean by that? Can you show example?

Comment: According to the document, Metadata would be passed like 
Metadata={ 'key(str)': 'value(str)' }
so it forms the meta info like "x-amz-meta-(key)": "(value)"
I would like to know how to put list into the 'value'
so desired example would be like
  "x-amz-meta-my_meta": {
    "my_meta_1": [
      "any_string"
    ]
  }

Comment: The metadata is returned as HTTP headers. The only way you could do that is to serialize it as json.